# Context.getCompilerVariable() returns null for compiler variable, defined in merged project

Tags: java, install4j

I am evaluating Install4j (version 7.0.8) and exploring its features - Merged project and custom code in separate JAR.

My tryout code base consists of 3 entities -

- Project Main.install4j
- Project SubMain.install4j - merged in project 'Main'.
- customcode.jar - Added as a resource in project 'Main'.

A compiler variable 'CV_Var1' is defined in Project 'SubMain' and is accessed in a function, defined in customcode.jar, as follows:

String strTemp = InstContext.getCompilerVariable("CV_Var1");

Upon executing the code, 'strTemp' is found null.

As per my observation, if variable 'CV_Var1' is defined in 'Main' instead of 'SubMain', variable value is retrieved successfully.

How to access compiler variable, defined in merged project, in custom code (placed in JAR)?
Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As of 7.0.8, compiler variables from merged projects are indeed not available at runtime. This will be fixed in 7.0.9. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Will go with your suggestion.